# Android GoogleMaps projection - farLeft vs nearLeft - what is the difference

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

googleMap.projection.visibleRegion has a few methods. there are such confusion on what they mean. im searching for the farthest latLang in the right and left directions. there is a farLeft and a nearLeft, likewise a farRight and a nearRight ? how exactly do they differ. from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/VisibleRegion) is not clear the difference between them:

[image]

if i have to divide the screen into 4 quadrants (1,2,3,4) then would it be correct to get the quadrants like this:

```
    val q1 = googleMap.projection.visibleRegion.farLeft
    val q2 = googleMap.projection.visibleRegion.farRight
    val q3 = googleMap.projection.visibleRegion.nearLeft
    val q4 = googleMap.projection.visibleRegion.nearRight
```

Answer (score 0):

GMSVisibleRegion contains the four points defining the polygon that is visible in a map's camera.

This polygon can be a trapezoid instead of a rectangle, because a camera can have tilt. If the camera is directly over the center of the camera, the shape is rectangular, but if the camera is tilted, the shape will appear to be a trapezoid whose smallest side is closest to the point of view.

#### Public Attributes

- nearLeft
       Bottom left corner of the camera.
- nearRight
       Bottom right corner of the camera.
- farLeft
       Far left corner of the camera.
- farRight
       Far right corner of the camera.